# Server 2008 EventLog levels

Tags: windows, events, windows-server-2008, event-log

Pre-2008 event log entries (of type EVENTLOGRECORD) had an EventType member that could be EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE, etc.

Since Vista, now there are Level and Keyword values instead of EventType.  I've searched high and low for what values Level and Keyword could hold but can't find any references.

Are there any official docs on this?  I'd hate to try and guess by looking at a lot of existing event log entries and hoping I guess right.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Found some docs

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382793(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382793%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/wes/wes/eventmanifestschema_keywordtype_complextype.htm](http://ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/wes/wes/eventmanifestschema_keywordtype_complextype.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the SDK header files in front of me, but I found the following information for the EventLogRecord managed class:

[EventLogRecord.Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.level.aspx)

[EventLogRecord.Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord.keywords.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Luke. You gave me the hint I needed to find the final answers:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382793(v=VS.85).aspx     and    ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/wes/wes/eventmanifestschema_keywordtype_complextype.htm (can't find an online version of this one)